# Identify the track playing in the background of this video titled "Water Dragon - Time-lapse"

Tags: identify-this-song, electronic-music

I’ve got a partial track and I would like to find:

- producer's name
- track name

It’s a YouTube video: [Water Dragon - Time-lapse](https://youtu.be/nm203qJED0U).

Any help is much appreciated. The genre is 'psychedelic dub'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artist: Liquid Stranger

Track:  The Molecule Man

Album:  The Arcane Terrain

Year:   2011

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjYsILeGrqw

Comment: BOOOOM!! Soooound my friend you don’t know how long I’ve been looking for that tracks name, I’ve never heard the whole track before I’ve woke up to this message and listened to the track straight away for that deepest respect it won’t let me vote you up cus of status on the music part of stack exchange but as soon as my rep is raised il upvote trust me l won’t forget

Comment: It was my pleasure to help out! Your kind response and gratitude is what keeps me here :) Glad to be of some service to you, cheers!

Comment: Sweet, if you enjoyed the track itself there is a web site which all music is free and it is all clean virus free released under the collective commons license where www.ektoplazm.com this is a brilliant site full of this genre and sub genres, I always share the site when I can it’s not mine but it should be shouted about because it’s full of inspiring music, I class it as new age classical, electronic symphonic, digital orchestra but they call it Pychedelic which it is very but I know people tend to.puush it aside when they think it involves drugs, see what you think it could open a new 